# USB ports are not working on HP laptop

Tags: usb, hp, usb-drive

The USB ports of my laptop are not working at all, It was running Ubuntu 22.04 then I updated to 23.04, to try to fix the problem. It does not detect them.

My laptop is a Hewlett Packard HP 2000 Notebook PC, with 4 GB RAM, i5-3230 CPU and Intel HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2).

Results of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05c8:0348 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP Truevision HD
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:3121 Qualcomm Atheros Communications
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Results of `dmesg -w | grep -i usb`: (https://pastebin.com/rgsvEFjC)

```
server@server-sami:~$ sudo dmesg -w | grep -i usb 
[    0.685680] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.685680] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.685680] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.685680] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.761425] pci 0000:00:1a.0: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x170 took 16916 usecs
[    0.781416] pci 0000:00:1d.0: quirk_usb_early_handoff+0x0/0x170 took 19499 usecs
[    1.480055] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.480221] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.497297] ehci-pci 0000:00:1a.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.497374] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.19
[    1.497378] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.497380] usb usb1: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.497382] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-41-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.497384] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1a.0
[    1.497579] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.497942] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.517321] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.517396] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.19
[    1.517399] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.517401] usb usb2: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.517403] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.19.0-41-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.517404] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.517637] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.517851] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.517873] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.753298] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.773297] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.909732] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    1.909737] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.910055] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.929729] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024, bcdDevice= 0.00
[    1.929734] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.930056] hub 2-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.197295] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.221297] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[    2.306619] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    2.306624] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.398856] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=05c8, idProduct=0348, bcdDevice= 1.07
[    2.398861] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[    2.398862] usb 2-1.3: Product: HP Truevision HD
[    2.398864] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Generic
[    2.398865] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: 200901010001
[   39.383281] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   39.921327] usb 2-1.3: Found UVC 1.00 device HP Truevision HD (05c8:0348)
[   39.941594] input: HP Truevision HD: HP Truevision as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/input/input8
[   39.941657] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   40.195521] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   40.397228] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   40.625304] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[   45.754804] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121, bcdDevice= 0.02
[   45.754820] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1361.106760] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 1361.106803] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 1361.215056] usb 1-1.1: device firmware changed
[ 1363.375657] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 1363.466682] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[ 1363.580556] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1363.580572] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1363.642729] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 1363.870649] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1363.980098] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121, bcdDevice= 0.02
[ 1363.980115] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1391.475872] usb 1-1.1: reset full-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[ 1391.487824] usb 2-1.3: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[ 1391.584112] usb 1-1.1: device firmware changed
[ 1393.873761] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1394.003733] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 1394.117205] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1394.117219] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[ 1394.268757] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
[ 1394.503818] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[ 1399.728727] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=3121, bcdDevice= 0.02
[ 1399.728737] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer? This sometimes fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes i have, it changes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible reasons why your USB ports are not working after updating to Ubuntu 23.04. Heere is one thing you can try.

Check if the USB driver is installed and updated: Check if the USB driver is installed and updated on your laptop. You can do this by going to the "Software & Updates" application and checking for updates. If there are any updates available, install them and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Sorry for not specifying that I update to try to fix he problem.